# Normalizing an exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, exponential-function

Given the equation $a^\frac yx + a^x=b$ is there a way to normalize this function into a form where $y=$...?

In short can I express $y$ in terms of $x$ if $a$ and $b$ are constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rewrite to $a^{y/x}=b-a^x$, then take the $\log$ on both sides to get $\frac{y}{x}\log(a) = \log(b-a^x)$.
Finally, we obtain
$$y = x\frac{\log(b-a^x)}{\log(a)}.$$

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How would you duplicate this if x and y are reversed?